# How do I set MIME type for APPLE APP SITE ASSOCIATION served using apache tomcat server?

Tags: ios, tomcat, deep-linking, ios-universal-links, apple-app-site-associate

I have this apple-app-site-association file under the .well-known directory. When I open the URL in browser JSON file shows up correctly but if I am validating using any of the validators I am getting following error.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Working receipt

```
<FilesMatch "apple-app-site-association">
    ForceType application/json
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: this is definitely the shortest answer I have found and google should pick it up as "make apache return apple-app-site-association as json"

Answer (score 1):

You can use the rewrite valve to set the content-type. Add the valve to your context.xml in META-INF:

```
<Context>
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve" />
</Context>
```

now place the apple-app-site-association file **with** the .json extension in the .well-known folder. Create a file named rewrite.config in WEB-INF with the following content:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /.well-known/apple-app-site-association
RewriteRule .* /.well-known/apple-app-site-association.json
```

now it you access https://host/.well-known/apple-app-site-association the json file will be delivered with content type set to application/json, this is the default mime mapping.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I've corrected it.